# How to get the value and the text in an Angular Material mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I need to get data of a mat-select specifically the text and its value. This is how I implemented the mat-select so far..

```html
<mat-select
  placeholder="Transaction Type"
  (selectionChange)="selected($event)"
  formControlName="TransactionTypeID"
>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let t of transactionTypes" [value]="t.TransactionTypeID">
    {{ t.TransactionType }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

This is how I get the value in the .ts file: `this.formDetail.get('TransactionTypeID').value,`

This is my attempt to get the text or 't.TransactionType':

```js
selected(event: MatSelectChange) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

Can you please show me how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Update : 2020** (Updated answer as per the new version of angular material)

The below old answer worked for the OP at the time question was asked. But I observed comments on the old answer and output event, `change` of `mat-select` has been deprecated in the new version of angular material. So, the correct answer is

### Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-example-krssfw?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="selectedValue($event)">
    <mat-option [value]="'GB'">Great Britain</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="'US'">United States</mat-option>
    <mat-option [value]="'CA'">Canada</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

> `selectionChange` will give us an object contains 2 properties `value` & `source`

- `value` will hold selected option value and
- To get the selected option text, you can simply call `triggerValue` on `source` like below

**TS:**

```
selectedValue(event: MatSelectChange) {
  this.selectedData = {
    value: event.value,
    text: event.source.triggerValue
  };
  console.log(this.selectedData);
}
```

---

---

---

### Old Answer

With normal change event, you can get the value like below

**In the .html file**

```
<mat-select placeholder="Transaction Type" (change)="selected($event)" formControlName="TransactionTypeID">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let t of transactionTypes" [value]="t.TransactionTypeID">
        {{t.TransactionType}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**In the .ts file**

```
selected(event) {
    let target = event.source.selected._element.nativeElement;
    let selectedData = {
      value: event.value,
      text: target.innerText.trim()
    };
    console.log(selectedData);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You really are a Javascript Lover =D.

Comment: Glad to hear that ;-), but please don't forgot to approving the answer!!!

Comment: This is no good.  Firstly, as of Material 7, the `change` event is now `selectionChange`.  Secondly, you cannot access `_element`.  @rodo's solution is the correct answer

Comment: Hi @SivakumarTadisetti .. Is it possible to have 3 properties? I have to get 3 values  (text, _id and um number) when user select a option.

Comment: @RobertoVieira can you provide the stackblitz with your problem? so will look into it

Comment: Thank you for the so elegant solution!

Answer (score 20):

To complete preceding answer one can use viewValue of MatOption.
Also Angular 7 compiler wants to know if *event.source.selected* should be an array or a single object.

```js
selected(event: MatSelectChange) {
  const selectedData = {
    text: (event.source.selected as MatOption).viewValue,
    value: event.source.value
  };
  console.log(selectedData);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It can easily do with this code.

**HTML**

```
 <mat-select value="option1" (selectionChange)=changeRatio($event)>
                <mat-option value="option0">Free Selection</mat-option>
                <mat-option value="option1">1 : 1.5 (Recommended)</mat-option>
 </mat-select>
```

**Angular TS**

```
  changeRatio(event: MatSelectChange) {
    console.log(event.value);
  }
```

Comment: Surely this should be the best answer, maybe during 2018 it was harder to obtain the value with mat-option

Answer (score 1):

```
onSeletected(e: MatSelectChange): void {
   setTimeout(() => {
     let control = this.getControl('documentInfo');
     control.setValue(e.source._elementRef.nativeElement.innerText);
  }, 500);    
}
```

I found solution for android 9, It worked for me. It would take time to change element after value change.

Comment: instead of using timeout u can calll this in "ngAfterViewInit"

Answer (score 0):

To get text and id of selected option:

**In the .html file**

```
<mat-select placeholder="Transaction Type" (change)="selected($event)" formControlName="TransactionTypeID">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let t of transactionTypes" [value]="t.TransactionType" [id]="t.TransactionTypeId">
        {{t.TransactionType}}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**In the .ts file**

```
import { MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent } from '@angular/material';
```

.....

```
selected(event:MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    let id = event.option.id;;
    let value = event.option.value;
    console.log("id = "+ id + ", value: " + value);
}
```